# Getting a MIMO UM-710S USB Powered 7 Inch LCD Mini Display to work

Tags: displaylink

Am interested in a satellite 7-10" display for my Thinkpad X201 (in addition to already running LCD and main laptop display). I've seen a bunch of mixed info regarding these devices which use Displaylink. Has anyone reliably gotten this to work? if so, how?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to install the `xserver-xorg-video-displaylink` package to get support for this class of devices (identifiable by connecting via USB and presenting a green screen on successful initialisation). The X server does not currently support hotplug events on the USB bus, so you will need to create an xorg.conf file to use such a device. An example xorg.conf file is included in the package (under `/usr/share/doc/xserver-xorg-video-displaylink/examples`).

If the above is not working for you, please [file a bug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) against xserver-xorg-video-displaylink: there may be some variation between displaylink devices, which may not be handled completely by the existing driver (but any such lack of support is a bug to be fixed, rather than a result of user error).